# Is there a way to call a method on an HTTPModule from a web page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I'm using an HTTPModule to do some simple work in the background of a web application.  I'm using a timer similar to what is described in this article:  [Using an HTTPModule to run a Background Service.](http://blogs.telerik.com/kevinbabcock/posts/08-07-24/Using_an_HttpModule_to_Run_a_Background_Service.aspx)

The problem is that the worker process never seems to terminate on its own, if no one's accessed the site in a long while.  I figure the problem is that the timer is never halted even after it's clear that there's no more work to do.  I can stop it, no problem, but I don't know a good way to know for sure when to restart it.  I'd like to have a method that I can call from the particular page that would be the "kick off" point for this process.  I suppose I could, alternatively, monitor BeginRequest for some URL to use as the trigger, but that feels kludgy.

I thought I was there with something like the line below, but something isn't right and I can't figure it out.
    `DirectCast(System.Web.HttpModuleCollection.Item("TimerBasedHTTPModule"), TimerBasedHTTPModule).StartPolling()`

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was close.

In my particular situation, this was the code I needed:

`DirectCast(HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Modules.Item("TimerBasedHTTPModule"), TimerBasedHTTPModule).StartPolling()`